# While loop - changing string variable

Tags: c, string, while-loop

As a newbie to c programming (I've only had experience in visual basic), I'm not entirely sure how a while loop with a changing string variable in its condition statement should function.

The following code is a simple calculator that I was making that allows the user to input an operation and two numbers, then output the respective result. I'am trying to code in a while loop that continually repeats the procedure until the user decides to exit it. However it seems that the line scanf("%c", &quit); isn't affecting the while loop condition statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
float num1, num2;
char operation;
char quit = "n";
while (quit = "n"){
printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /) \n");
scanf(" %c", &operation);
printf("Enter the numbers you wish to carry out the operation on \n");
scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);
    switch(operation) {
        case '+':
            printf("%f\n", num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%f\n", num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%f\n", num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%f\n", num1/num2);
            break;

    }
printf("Would you like quit the program, is so enter 'y' \n");
scanf("%c", &quit);
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: `char quit = "n";` is not C.

Comment: read up on the difference between single quotes and double quotes

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.

Comment: Will definitely read up on the difference, currently using integers in the program for the yes and no option, seems to be working fine like that, but will modify it once I've learned more. Thanks everyone for the help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @twalberg - all my compiler warnings are enabled and they really do help in ensuring I'm not missing anything stupid out. Didn't seem to pick up anything wrong with this piece of code though.

Comment: I also found out that I was missing a space in the scanf line I mentioned above - so it should of instead been: scanf(" %c", &quit); -. I believe it has something to do with the automatic new line that the scanf function has, not entirely sure though, would be grateful if someone could clear this up.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That's because you're assigning the value of the quit variable in your while loop, instead of checking for its value.

Use == for =

```
while(quit == "n"){...}
```

Comment: While the choice of operator is certainly, wrong, this isn't right, either. You can't compare a single character to a static string literal that way and expect to get anything meaningful out of it...

Comment: Thanks for the help, such a simple error, never even knew there was a different operation for checking values, - as in visual basic, a single equal sign seems to do both functions - .

Comment: This answer did solve the issue I was having, I think the negative votes are solely because double quotes were used on a single character instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
float num1, num2;
char operation;
char quit = 'n';
//while (quit = "n") //
  while (quit!= 'y')
 {
printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /) \n");
scanf(" %c", &operation);
printf("Enter the numbers you wish to carry out the operation on \n");
scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);
switch(operation) {
    case '+':
        printf("%f\n", num1+num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%f\n", num1-num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%f\n", num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("%f\n", num1/num2);
        break;

}
printf("Would you like quit the program, is so enter 'y' \n");
scanf("%c", &quit);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

replace `while (quit = "n")` with `while (quit! = 'y')`